# Composite Primary Key On Table Variable In Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, primary-key

I'm new to stored procedures and trying to add a composite primary key to a table variable.

```
DECLARE @statistictemp TABLE (
    MajorName      VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    SubName       VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    DetailedName   VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    UniversityID   SMALLINT    NOT NULL, 
    StatisticValue DECIMAL(9,3)
);

ALTER TABLE @statistictemp 
ADD CONSTRAINT pk_statistictemp 
PRIMARY KEY (MajorName, SubName, DetailedName, UniversityID);
```

I'm getting an error on `ALTER TABLE @statistictemp` saying

> `Incorrect syntax near '@statistictemp'. Expecting ID, QUOTED_ID, or
>   '.'.`

What am I doing wrong here? How do you add a composite primary key to a table variable?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
DECLARE @statistictemp TABLE (
    MajorName       VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    SubName        VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    DetailedName    VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    UniversityID    SMALLINT NOT NULL, 
    StatisticValue  DECIMAL(9,3),
    PRIMARY KEY (MajorName, SubName, DetailedName, UniversityID)
);
```

You can test that the primary key constraint works by trying to insert duplicates:
e.g.,

```
INSERT INTO @statistictemp(MajorName, SubName, DetailedName, UniversityID) SELECT 'a','b','c',1
INSERT INTO @statistictemp(MajorName, SubName, DetailedName, UniversityID) SELECT 'a','b','c',1
```

The second statement will throw an error:

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 13
>   Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_*#1EA48E8*_B595483D208CD6FA'. Cannot insert duplicate key in
>   object 'dbo.@statistictemp'.
>   The statement has been terminated.